# Getting error in Executing BLOSUM62 matix

Tags: python, matrix, biopython

I'm trying to extract data from `blosum62` matrix

I have done the following code:

```
from Bio.SubsMat import MatrixInfo    
blosum = MatrixInfo.blosum62    
blosum['N','D']
```

et gets following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<stdin>", line 1, in  <module>
>   KeyError: ('N', 'D')

But in `blosum62` matrix there is a value of `('N','D') = 1`

Why is it giving KeyError ?

Comment: There is no key `("N", "D")` in the blosum62 matrix. Print `blosum` and see for yourself. There's a `("D", "N")`, though.

Comment: http://etutorials.org/Misc/blast/Part+II+Theory/Chapter+4.+Sequence+Similarity/4.3+Scoring+Matrices/ 
look this link . value of (N,D) is 1

Comment: That's great, but it's not in Biopython, so your code isn't going to work.

Comment: I think blosum62 is a lower triangular matrix that's why it is not working. 
I have seen that blosum('N','D') is not working but blosum('D','N') is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think Blosum62 is a lower triangular matrix so if ('N','D') is not working then go with ('D','N')

the solution is

```
pair = ('N','D')
if pair not in blosum62_matrix:
      value = blosum62_matrix[(tuple(reversed(pair)))]
else:
      value = blosum62_matrix[pair]
```

I think it will work.

Answer (score -1):

Accroding to http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/api/Bio.SubsMat.MatrixInfo-module.html#blosum62 `blosom62` returns a dictionary. So try `blosum[('N','D')]`.

Comment: Please test your code before answering. There is no `("N", "D")` key in the blosum62 matrix.

Comment: I checked the sources. There is such a key. In the link I provided it's not shown.

Comment: Yes, I checked the link. I also ran your code, and it gave the same `KeyError` as the OP's code. I then sorted and printed out the `blosum62` dict, and, lo and behold, there is no `("N", "D")` key. You are correct that the keys are tuples, though.

Comment: Please give me the line number in the source where `("N", "D")` appears *and* is assigned to `blosum62`. I'm using Biopython 1.68, the latest version, and it appears in 5 matrices - `johnson`, `levin`, `nwsgappep`, `rao`, and `risler`. `('D', 'N')` appears in `blosum62`, but not `('N', 'D')`.

Comment: My apologies. I checked the sources again. You're right, the `('N', 'D')` key is only in those 5 matrices. I thought I saw in the `blosum62` matrix.